# Get the size of SwiftUI named coordinate space

Tags: swiftui

When you define a coordinate space using [coordinateSpace(name:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/coordinatespace(name:)), you can use [frame(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy/frame(in:)) in some other view to get the rectangle of a geometry reader relative to the coordinate space. From that other view, how can you get the size of the coordinate space itself?